# Unable to publish API for Extractor on Import.io without Javascript

Tags: import.io

I'm starting to go a bit insane here, so hopefully someone out there can assist. I'm trying to use import.io to get the name and price of a product from a shopping site. In particular, I'm doing my testing on this URL: http://www.roddandgunn.com/clothing/knitwear/Urquhart%20Peak%20Knit/Urquhart-Peak-Knit.html

However, I'm unable to get import.io to publish an API which is only fetching the product name at this point. I've manually overridden the XPath, javascript is disabled for the page, but every time I try to publish I get "The API failed to publish" error.

This is the text that shows up when I display the JSON:

```
{
    "offset": 0,
    "connectorGuid": "023f6433-7553-4d17-8036-924c9434c7ba",
    "results": [
        {
            "clothing_name": "Westown Wool Coat"
        }
    ],
    "title": "Rodd & Gunn | Authentic Range - Westown Wool Coat",
    "pageUrl": "http://www.roddandgunn.com/authentic-range/Westown%20Wool%20Coat/Westown-Wool-Coat.html"
}
```

(right hand side):

```
{
    "extraction": {
        "resultPipeline": [
            {
                "configuration": {
                    "property": "clothing_name",
                    "xpaths": [
                        "//h1[@itemprop='name']"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "resultXPaths": [
            "/html/body"
        ]
    },
    "urlProperties": [],
    "version": 4,
    "playback": {
        "fixHtml": true,
        "url": "${webpage/url}"
        }
}
```

I don't know how I can simplify it down any further, and thus I'm not sure why it refuses to let me publish an API for it. Does anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

import.io's servers are based in the US which means they use US-based IP addresses.

Why is this important?

If you connect to the URL through a US proxy service (to mirror what import.io does when it publishes), the website displayed is different, import.io gets redirected, and it cannot see your data!

The fix for this is quite simple, (after digging around on the site and playing with a few proxies)

You can tell the server to display the right version of the website by adding the following to the end of your URL:

`isams=setsite&wsid=2`

for example:
`http://www.roddandgunn.com/clothing/knitwear/Urquhart%20Peak%20Knit/Urquhart-Peak-Knit.html?isams=setsite&wsid=2`

It publishes!
`https://import.io/data/mine/?id=ae62a9b1-5adb-438e-a17b-78d528a1cde2`

if you want to pass more URLs through the extractor, you'll need to add the `isams=setsite&wsid=2` to the other urls you want to extract.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Javascript on the page when you're training your Extractor. 
On **Detect Optimal Settings**, select *No* then *Yes*.

From [Detect Optimal Settings](http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/247566-why-do-we-detect-optimal-settings):

*Detecting optimal settings will change the settings of the browser by first turning off cookies and javascript, so that the system will have the best chance of extracting data.*

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I don't believe it is correct. Enabling Javascript doesn't resolve the issue, and seems to go against the advice on the [FAQ page](http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/403410-couldn-t-create-an-api) for **Timeout issues** which says to disable Javascript.